# Parsing JSON array with PHP foreach

Tags: php, foreach, json

Wondering why my PHP code will not display all "Value" of "Values" in the JSON data:

```
$user = json_decode(file_get_contents($analytics));
foreach($user->data as $mydata)
{
     echo $mydata->name . "\n";

}        
foreach($user->data->values as $values)
{
     echo $values->value . "\n";
}
```

The first foreach works fine, but the second throws an error.

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "id": "MY_ID/insights/page_views_login_unique/day",
         "name": "page_views_login_unique",
         "period": "day",
         "values": [
            {
               "value": 1,
               "end_time": "2012-05-01T07:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value": 6,
               "end_time": "2012-05-02T07:00:00+0000"
            },
            {
               "value": 5,
               "end_time": "2012-05-03T07:00:00+0000"
            }, ...
```

Comment: What's the error? Tell us what the output is.

Comment: Is `$user->data` an array? Because you go trough it with foreach.

Comment: Error is:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().  $user->data appears to be an array of [0];

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You maybe wanted to do the following:

```
foreach($user->data as $mydata)

    {
         echo $mydata->name . "\n";
         foreach($mydata->values as $values)
         {
              echo $values->value . "\n";
         }
    }
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for!  Strange, I thought I have tried this, thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much this is what I was looking for !

Comment: Simple yet elegant solution :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to tell it which index in `data` to use, or double loop through all.

E.g., to get the values in the 4th index in the outside array.:

```
foreach($user->data[3]->values as $values)
{
     echo $values->value . "\n";
}
```

To go through all:

```
foreach($user->data as $mydata)
{
    foreach($mydata->values as $values) {
        echo $values->value . "\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

`$user->data` is an array of objects.  Each element in the array has a `name` and `value` property (as well as others).

Try putting the 2nd `foreach` inside the 1st.

```
foreach($user->data as $mydata)
{
    echo $mydata->name . "\n";
    foreach($mydata->values as $values)
    {
        echo $values->value . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thank you @Rocket this is what I needed, Jonas answered first =p

Comment: @ToddN: Darn, beaten by 76 seconds :-P