# Sending data using ajax json and phrasing in php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I'm passing stringify JSON like this to my php file,

```
[{"Country Code":"bob","Country":"503","Description":"bobby","\"Minute Rate":"oregon","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":"steve","Country":"707","Description":"stevie","\"Minute Rate":"california","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":"dsfd","Country":"342","Description":"dfdfs","\"Minute Rate":"dfdsfs","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":"sada","Country":"342","Description":"sdsad","\"Minute Rate":"dfsffd","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":""}]
```

How can i run a loop to fetch these **results in php?**

Thank you!

Comment: use json_decode() to convert the values in array and then use foreach loop.

Comment: Hope this link helps u .. 

  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758897/parsing-json-array-with-php-foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
$json='[{"Country Code":"bob","Country":"503","Description":"bobby","\"Minute Rate":"oregon","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":"steve","Country":"707","Description":"stevie","\"Minute Rate":"california","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":"dsfd","Country":"342","Description":"dfdfs","\"Minute Rate":"dfdsfs","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":"sada","Country":"342","Description":"sdsad","\"Minute Rate":"dfsffd","USD\"":"","\"$5 Talk Time":"\r"},{"Country Code":""}]';
$result=json_decode($json, true);
foreach($result as $value)
{
echo $value['Country Code'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**json_decode** function takes a json string for its first parameter and an optional boolean (true/false) for its second parameter. The second parameter, if set to true, returns the json string as an associative array, if it’s not set it will return an object.

```
json_array  = json_decode($json, true); //Converts to array
    foreach($json_array as $json){
       echo $json['key']; //Key
       echo $json->key;  //Value of key
    }
```

**FYI**

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
json_decode(string, true);
```

Result will be an array and you can loop it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
<?php
$jsonObject = json_decode($yourstring);
echo $jsonObject->{'json-key'};
?>
```