# How to parse JSON from a URL with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have this URL:

```
http://server.com/api.php?results

{"Name":"Pit, Loka","Current":{"Item":"16","test":"test","test":"84","test":"ok"}}
```

I guess the PHP Example is:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("http://server.com/api.php?results=item");
$data = json_decode($file);
print_r($data);
?>
```

but I can't get any results.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can u get the result on the browser?

Comment: Check the errors you receive. You either didn't get the contents or json decoding failed. Implement error checks.

Comment: Try some debugging: try `echo`-ing the string in `$file`, is it empty? Are you seeing any errors ? (`error_reporting(E_ALL)`)

Comment: Did you try `var_dump()` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON array with PHP foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758897/parsing-json-array-with-php-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("http://server.com/api.php?results=item");
$data = json_decode($file);

$name = $data->Name; // "Name":"Pit, Loka"
$current = $data->Current->Item; //"Current":{"Item":"16","test":"test","test":"84","test":"ok"}

foreach ($current as $currentX) {
    echo $currentX->Item;
}
?>
```

It should work... please test.