# Get result out of nested Json with php

Tags: php, json

I want to retrieve a value out of a nested JSON file with PHP. I created the following code:

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("https://api.abc");
$json = json_decode($string,true);
foreach ($json['contacts'][0]['properties']['company'] as $person) {

  echo $person['value'];
}
?>
```

It will only give me 1 result and only the first letter of the value. How do I get more results and more than just the first letter?

```
{
    "contacts": [{
        "addedAt": 1414182103652,
        "vid": 2,
        "canonical-vid": 2,
        "merged-vids": [],
        "portal-id": 448845,
        "is-contact": true,
        "properties": {
            "firstname": {
                "value": "Andre"
            },
            "lastmodifieddate": {
                "value": "1472024018755"
            },
            "company": {
                "value": "test"
            },
            "lastname": {
                "value": "Jansen"
            }
        },
```

Comment: Without seeing contents of `$json` we can't say anything

Comment: show your json data.

Comment: Thanks for th quick response here is a snapshot of the JSON:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,
use only `$person` on the place of `$person['value']`

```
$json = json_decode($string,true);
foreach ($json['contacts'][0]['properties']['company'] as $person) {
  echo $person;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/hKdhs)**

Comment: Thanks that did it and if i want to loop it do i need to remove the 0?

Comment: see this,it will help you for loop of json http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758897/parsing-json-array-with-php-foreach

Comment: Thanks Dave for this !